# CSS rule is not applying to image

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to apply CSS changes to an image added in HTML but the changes are not applying, here is what I have

HTML

```
<section id = "firstimage">
  <div class = "container">
<img src = "collage2.jpg">
</section>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  width:80%;
  margin:auto
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

}

#firstimage
{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are applying css to the `<section id="firstimage">` not the `img` element. And also, remember to close the `div`. Try the following instead.

```
<section id="firstimage">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="collage2.jpg">
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  width:80%;
  margin:auto
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#firstimage img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

With the css above, you're applying the styles to the actual `img` element.

Answer (score 0):

try closing the div

```
<section id="firstimage">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg">
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Delete all space from before equal(=) and after equal(=) and close container div after img wrap**

```
<section id="firstimage">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="collage2.jpg">
  </div>
</section>
```